"Your X and y-axis values aren't playing together nicely" error with simple numeric and datetime data
I'm new to PowerBI. I'm more familiar with Plotly and Spotfire.
I'm trying to create what (to me) seems to be an incredibly basic scatter plot with datetime on the x-axis and a decimal on the y-axis. To troubleshoot this error I've filtered the data down to a simple, 11 row, 4 column table - but the error persists.

The actual data I'm attempting to chart (compound name and the datttime-copy aren't being used but can be re-generated manually) ...
injection_acquireddate,tailingfactor
2019-03-22 16:45:21,1.0018661915117595
2019-03-22 17:02:40,1.0091641386049404
2019-03-22 17:19:55,1.015032972331727
2019-03-22 17:37:18,1.0115925262538266
2019-03-22 17:54:33,1.0070131174288117
2019-03-22 18:11:53,1.001438858221776
2019-03-22 18:29:09,0.9768981217761633
2019-03-22 19:53:22,1.0150662205451095
2019-03-22 20:10:42,1.0084349518517708
2019-03-22 20:27:58,1.016205896945317
2019-03-22 21:02:36,1.0054275815845197

I try to make a Scatter chart in PowerBI and I get the error. Very simply, I want a scatter plot with all 11 of the datetimes on the X and all 11 of the actual complete decimal values on the Y. The tailingfactor is not aggregated.
If I aggregate the tailingfactor data as "sum" - it more or less funcitons as a work around (the sum on one value is the value) except summing it ruins the decimal (I.e. 1.0018661915117595 becomes 1.0100000000000000)
This seems like it would be the most basic type of charting possible. Can anyone explain why the error is happening and how to fix it?

Chart...


x-axis

y-axis


You need to make sure you put the date as the X/Y axis field, you are currently using it as the value field.

@Oxbowerce Good catch, and sorry about that. I had been adding it to the y-axis, I just screwed up when I recreated the chart for this post. It is now added to the y-axis, and the injection date to the x...with the identical results and identical error.

I think the error is then caused by the fact that one your axis fields is a date, which Power BI doesn't like. An alternative would be to use the line plot, and if you really want it to be a scatter plot change some settings for the visual (see this stackoverflow answer).

@Oxbowerce
I managed to get both a lone chart AND a scatter plot working. I'm...not even actually sure how. The only thing I chnaged was, when I filtered all the nulls out of all three columns, a selected to filter on BOTH "is not blank" and "is not empty." I dont know what the difference is, but doing so seemed to work.

OK. It seems I got the scatter to work with datetime on the X and decimal on the Y.
It's weird.
First, you have to create a line chart and get that working with the data where you want it.
Then if you convert it to a scatter chart, it will keep working.
You also still have to average the data points. It seems, if you use a legend, that it is still taking the "average" of only one datapoint (I.e. value / 1) but if you select "dont summarize" (when it appears) it again does't work.
As an aside, I also filtered all the columns by BOTH "is not blank" AND "is not empty."

